# Set maximum payload (message) size for websockets in Postman

Tags: websocket, postman

In Postman, in Settings, we can set maximum payload size, but that applies to REST payloads. It seems it doesn't affect the WS data size, and it breaks with `Error: Max payload size exceeded` for big data.
How we can set maximum size for WS payload?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is not one place to set that option globally for all WS connections, instead you have to set it for each connection individually.

In websocket connection settings (under the address bar, where it says `Params | Headers | **Settings**`, option named `Maximum message size`.